# Affixing a 5kg mirror to an outdoor wall

Tags: walls

I would like to  mount a 4-5kg   (*10-11 lbs*)  30" circular    wood mirror on a courtyard wall that occasionally gets strong winds. The mirror currently has two hooks at the top.

Can you suggest a way to affix it to the wall in such a way as to mitigate potential issues during stormy (*windy*) weather?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How permanent?  Does the wall have a smooth surface?  Is it painted?

Comment: How about a picture of the mirror and the wall you want to attach it to.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "wood mirror".  If the mirror is *securely* mounted to a wood frame there are easy ways to fasten the wood to the wall.  Is it?  And what is the wall made of?

Comment: Wood mirror?, Stormy weather, Wet wood! "*Courtyard wall*", Block, brick, wood, stucco? *Wood mirror, Now i gotta go polish my wood to see if i can make it reflective*.

Comment: Possibly a photo of the mirror would provide superior answers a pic of the mirror and wall so we would know the conditions like an out door shower next to a hot tub,pool or at a beach house would provide what some of may have even done in the past.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I've added a photo of the mirror and wall as requested. Not a permanent fix.... Looking for a strong hold through wind, that can also be easily removed in case of extreme storms.

Comment: And , there is a good chance moisture will get to the aluminum reflecting surface and corrode it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how permanent you want it to be and the surface you want to fix it to, a backboard and or adhesive would do the trick.  For less permanent options, build either large or many mirror clips out of some similar wood or pre-set a backboard of the same size and drill and countersink nice screws through the edge of the frame where there is no glass.  If safe frame thickness is substantial, you could recess the backboard 15mm from the edge of the mirror frame and add indirect weatherproof RGB lighting strips in the recess for a nice garish touch.  Mirror clips are probably your best option as they are secure and won't damage the frame and a wide array of aesthetics will be available even if you have to make them yourself.

To elaborate on what I mean by building your own mirror clips:

Here is an image of 3 common types of mirror clip, all far too small for you to use:

[image: 3 mirror clip types]

You need 3 mirror clips to firmly secure a round mirror.

The first type has a lot of meat to it, so you could build a variety of similar shapes out of wood.  The type of fasteners you'd need depend on the wall you're attaching to.

The second type Would work well in wood as well.  Note the convenient seam shown in the picture.  The bottom clips could be solid and the top clip made in two pieces so the front can be screwed on once the mirror is in place.  With the right design, screws can be hidden on top for a flat face.

The third type would be easy to make in 1/8" thick flat iron.  For the size mirror you have I'd use 1.5" wide.  You can see that a slot is provided for the screw so that two screws can be used to hold the bottom clips without moving and a single screw can be used on the top clip so it can be slid to remove the mirror.  The modification I'd make for a large version is to have the base about 4-5" long and have two slots cut in it so it can slide up and down but not rotate.  1/8" flat is very easy to work with, I built this exact shape just last year for ladder hangers.  To bend round 90 degree bends, use a blowtorch and vise, heat directly the part you want to bend and clamp extra layers of flat or angle to the parts you don't want to bend.  Heat and bend.  For tight 90 degree bends, make sure your vise is firmly mounted to the workbench and the workbench strong, clamp the flat in the vise so the top edge of the vise is where you want your bend.  Apply a small amount of pressure 20" away in the direction you want the flat to bend and use a 3-5 pound sledge hammer to strike the flat close to the jaw of the vise.  Don't try to do it in one hit.  To make the second bend, the jaws of your vise may not be deep enough because of the L shape sticking out from your first bend.  Use a steel block to extend the vise jaw.

Comment: A 30” mirror on a base board, I don’t think they want to lay on the ground to use it.  Mirror clips with a wooden frame? I don’t see that working.

Comment: K h I was mentioning things to help you improve your answer some will downvote but it appears it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a 10 inch or so aluminum French cleat.  Can you glue a 3/4" plywood "backing" to the mirror?  If so, you could screw the cleat to the backing.  If the wall is hollow, and the studs are not in a convenient place, you could use a couple toggle bolts for that part.  At the bottom of the mirror, you should attach an inconspicuous clip to the bottom of the mirror, so it won't lift in the wind.

Stepping back a bit, consider that the wooden frame appears to be made up of a dozen or more glued pieces of wood. Does it need to be weather-proof in addition to resisting gusty winds?  Maybe look at some other mirrors?